# VS code - отключить клавишу alt

Tags: visual-studio-code, клавиатура

Как отключить клавишу **alt** в Vusial Studio code?
У меня **Сaps Lock** переключает раскладку, с помощью программы-эмулятора: **shift + alt** ,и видимо из-за небольшой задержки или программного переключения VS code думает, что нажата клавиша **alt** и показывает/скрывает меню программы, что очень мешает.

Answer (score 3):

[image: Отключаем реакцию бара на ALT]

Заходим в параметры 
вводим ALT, 
Переходим в параметры пользователя 
Выбираем окно 
находим Enable Menu Bar Mnemonics
Снимаем галку. 
Вуаля!

Answer (score 1):

Как оказалось дело даже не в alt. Перепробовав разные настройки, снес эмулятор и поставил Punto Switcher. Таким образом, проблема решилась.

Answer (score 1):

Мне помогли следующие настройки:

```
"window.titleBarStyle": "custom",
"window.customMenuBarAltFocus": false
```

Не забудьте перезагрузить редактор.